# XSLT; only output parent node based on missing specific child attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, output, xslt-1.0, nodes

I'm very new to XML and XSL and I seem to keep circling this problem and I'm not finding a solution that fits my needs.

I have an XSL that is displaying my XML data in the proper format and layout. My issue is that I would like to have certain duplicated parts overlooked by the XSL based on the missing "slope" field under the CrossSectionSegment part.

A clip of my XML data that has 1 point with "slope" field and 1 without (out of thousands):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<InRoads productName="Power InRoads V8i (SELECTseries 2)" productVersion="08.11.07.615" outputGridScaleFactor="1.000000" inputGridScaleFactor="1.000000" linearUnits="Metric" angularUnits="Degrees" commandName="Cross Section Report">
    <CrossSectionSet setID="12" setName="assiginack_1" alignmentOID="{F3AC8C7A-D9A2-44C3-B154-611FA05E38F6}" alignmentName="assiginack">
        <CrossSectionStations>
            <CrossSectionStation leftOffset="-9.345000" rightOffset="7.683000" tangentialDirection="0.918685" radialDirection="2.489481" northing="5058046.825198" easting="346212.772114" elevation="0.000000" longitudinalGrade="0.000000">
                <Station internalStation="10300.000000" externalStationName="" externalStation="10300.000000"/>
                <CrossSectionSurfaces>
                    <CrossSectionSurface name="Assi_Design" type="1">
                        <CrossSectionPoints>
                          <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="5058044.240230" easting="346214.745845" offset="3.252333" elevation="229.294167">
                                <CrossSectionFeatures>
                                    <CrossSectionFeature name="REP" style="EOP" description="Created by roadway design" aheadLongitudinalSlope="0.038977"/>
                                </CrossSectionFeatures>
                                <CrossSectionSegment width="1.687000" height="-0.038567" length="1.687441" slope="-0.022861"/>
                            </CrossSectionPoint>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="5058044.239700" easting="346214.746249" offset="3.253000" elevation="229.294136">
                                <CrossSectionFeatures>
                                    <CrossSectionFeature name="REP" style="EOP" description="Created by roadway design" aheadLongitudinalSlope="0.038977"/>
                                </CrossSectionFeatures>
                                <CrossSectionSegment width="0.000667" height="-0.000031" length="0.000667" averageCrossSlopeArea="0.050057"/>
                            </CrossSectionPoint>
                        </CrossSectionPoints>
                    </CrossSectionSurface>
                </CrossSectionSurfaces> 
            </CrossSectionStation>
        </CrossSectionStations>
    </CrossSectionSet>
</InRoads>
```

I'm intending on having the second "REP" Cross Section Point in the XML clip to be overlooked and keep the first based on the fact that it has the "slope" field and the second doesn't. Or, the opposite could work, exclude points that have the averageCrossSlopeArea field. (I have other points that are duplicating as well and are not specifically called "REP").

This is the XSL that i was handed and have made some modifications to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:inr="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace">
    <xsl:include href="../format.xsl"/>
    <xsl:param name="xslRootDirectory" select="inr:xslRootDirectory"/>
    <!-- Unique cross section surfaces -->
    <xsl:variable name="uniqueSurfaceName" select="//CrossSectionSurfaces/CrossSectionSurface[not (@name = preceding::CrossSectionSurface/@name)]/@name"/>    
    <!-- Slope Stake Listing -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="gridOut" select="inr:SetGridOut(number(InRoads/@outputGridScaleFactor))"/>
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$xslRootDirectory}/_Themes/engineer/document.css"/>
                <!-- Title displayed in browser Title Bar -->
                <title lang="en">Slope Stake Listing</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$xslShowHelp = 'true'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="StyleSheetHelp"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:for-each select="InRoads">
                            <center>
                                <!-- Report Title -->
                                <h6 lang="en">SLOPE STAKE LISTING</h6>
                                <p lang="en">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="inr:longDate()"/>&#xa0; <xsl:value-of select="inr:longTime()"/>
                                </p>
                            </center>
                            <!-- Cross Section Set Data -->
                            <xsl:for-each select="CrossSectionSet">
                                <table class="margin">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td lang="en">Set Name:&#xa0; </td>
                                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@setName"/></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td lang="en">Project Units:&#xa0; </td>
                                            <td lang="en">
                                                <xsl:if test="//@linearUnits = 'Imperial'">US Survey Feet</xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="//@linearUnits = 'Metric'">Metric</xsl:if>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td lang="en">Contract No.:&#xa0; </td>
                                            <td>&#xa0;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td lang="en">Co./Rte./PM:&#xa0; </td>
                                            <td>&#xa0;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <hr/>
                                <!-- Cross Section Point Data -->
                                <table class="margin" width="90%">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="$uniqueSurfaceName[../@type = 1]">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="//CrossSectionSurface[@name = current()]">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="CrossSectionPoints">
                                                <!-- Alignment Name -->
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th colspan="11" lang="en">
                                                        Alignment Chain:&#xa0; <xsl:value-of select="../../../../../@alignmentName"/>
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <!-- Station -->
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th colspan="11" lang="en">
                                                        Station:&#xa0; <xsl:value-of select="inr:stationFormat(number(../../../Station/@externalStation), $xslStationFormat,$xslStationPrecision, string(../../../Station/@externalStationName))"/>
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <!-- Feature Name -->
                                                <tr>                                                    
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="CrossSectionPoint[CrossSectionFeatures/CrossSectionFeature/@name] | CrossSectionPoint[not (CrossSectionFeatures/CrossSectionFeature/@name) and (@offset &gt; -0.1 and @offset &lt; 0.1)]">                                                                                                                  
                                                        <th>
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="CrossSectionFeatures/CrossSectionFeature/@name"/>
                                                        </th>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>                                                    
                                                </tr>
                                                <!-- Offset -->
                                                <tr>                                                    
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="CrossSectionPoint[CrossSectionFeatures/CrossSectionFeature/@name] | CrossSectionPoint[not (CrossSectionFeatures/CrossSectionFeature/@name) and (@offset &gt; -0.1 and @offset &lt; 0.1)]">
                                                        <td align="center" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;white-space:nowrap;">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="inr:distanceFormat(number(@offset), $xslDistancePrecision)"/>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>                                                    
                                                </tr>
                                                <!-- Elevation -->
                                                <tr>                                                    
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="CrossSectionPoint[CrossSectionFeatures/CrossSectionFeature/@name] | CrossSectionPoint[@offset &gt; -0.0001 and @offset &lt; 0.0001]">
                                                        <td align="center" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;white-space:nowrap;">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="inr:elevationFormat(number(@elevation), $xslElevationPrecision)"/>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>                                                    
                                                </tr>
                                                <!-- Slope -->
                                                <tr>                                                    
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="CrossSectionPoint[CrossSectionFeatures/CrossSectionFeature/@name] | CrossSectionPoint[not (CrossSectionFeatures/CrossSectionFeature/@name) and (@offset &gt; -0.1 and @offset &lt; 0.1)]">
                                                        <td align="center" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;white-space:nowrap;">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="inr:alternateGradeFormat(number(CrossSectionSegment/@slope), $xslGradeFormat, $xslGradePrecision, $xslIfSlopeExceeds, $xslAlternateSlopeFormat, $xslAlternateSlopePrecision)"/>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>                                                    
                                                </tr>                                             
                                                <tr><td>&#xa0;</td></tr>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </table>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <msxsl:script implements-prefix="inr" language="JScript">
        <![CDATA[
            // This function gets the current date.
            function longDate()
            {
                var today = new Date();
                var month = today.getMonth();
                var monthName = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
                var dayOfMonth = today.getDate();
                if (dayOfMonth < 10)
                {
                    dayOfMonth = "0" + dayOfMonth;
                }
                var year = today.getFullYear();
                return monthName[today.getMonth()] + " " + dayOfMonth + ", " + year;
            }
            // This function gets the current time.
            function longTime()
            {
                var today = new Date();
                var hours = today.getHours();
                var setting = "";
                if (hours == 12)
                {
                    setting = "PM";
                }
                if (hours == 24)
                {
                    setting = "AM";
                }
                if (hours < 12)
                {
                    setting = "AM";
                }
                if (hours > 12)
                {
                    setting = "PM";
                    hours = hours - 12;
                }
                var minutes = today.getMinutes();
                if (minutes < 10)
                {
                    minutes = "0" + minutes;
                }
                var seconds = today.getSeconds();
                if (seconds < 10)
                {
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;
                    }
                return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + setting;
            }
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
    <xsl:template name="StyleSheetHelp">
        <div class="section1">
            <h4 lang="en">Notes</h4>
            <p class="normal1" lang="en">
                You must have created cross sections along your alignment and the cross section set must 
                have the surfaces and features upon which you wish to report displayed.
            </p>
            <p class="normal1" lang="en">
                You can create the XML data file from the <em>Evaluation &gt; Cross Section &gt; Cross 
                Section Report</em> command or from the <em>End-Area Volumes</em> leaf of the <em>
                Evaluation &gt; Cross Section &gt; Cross Sections</em> command by toggling on the <em>
                Create XML Report</em> option on the <em>General</em> leaf.
            </p>
            <p class="normal1" lang="en">
                This report works only with surfaces whose <em>Type</em> on the <em>Main</em> tab of the 
                <em>Surface &gt; Surface Properties</em> command is set to <em>Design</em>.&#xa0; It works 
                best if all features (except the catchpoints) included in the XML data file have 
                names.&#xa0; There should also be a point at the center line for best results.&#xa0; 
                Components are not reported.
            </p>
            <p class="small" lang="en">
                <em>&#xa9; 2010 Bentley Systems, Inc</em>
            </p>
        </div>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have created a public link to my formatting file called format.xsl here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48414836/format.xsl

This image shows both the proper and improper outputs: [Improper and Proper Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIrCN.jpg)

I would greatly appreciate some help with this since I have done a lot of research and have tried multiple different solutions from many different sites with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please minimize your example to the problem at hand and make it complete -- see: [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have shortened my question and data and I have also reworded it.  I also included the format file required to check it. Like i said in my question I am very new to XML/XSLT and I'm not sure how to shorten my XSL anymore. Hopefully this is enough for you to be able to help. Thanks.

Comment: Let me suggest you include two **pairs** of points in the example input, and show the expected output (as code, within your question).